# Validation multiple checkbox form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in the page I have only three checkbox, the client should choose at least one before clicking on the submit button :

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Client(OrderItems model)
{
  if (bValidated){
  //Code here
}
else
{ 
  model.itemChoosed = false;
  return View("Client", model);
}
```

View Client :

```
@model WebApp.Models.OrderItems

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Client", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", role = "form" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <h2>Client</h2>
    @Html.Partial("SentMessage")

  <div>
    <div>
        <h3>Item 1</h3>
        <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CLInfo.Item1)  Item 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Item 2</h3>
        <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CLInfo.Item2)  Item 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Item 3</h3>
        <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CLInfo.Item3)  Item 3</label>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" name="action:Client" id="btnClient" class="btn btn-primary flat btn-large pull-right" value="Client" />
</div>
 }
```

After I choose to put the condition into a Partail View :
Partial View SentMessage:

```
@model WebApp.Models.OrderItems
@if (!model.itemChoosed) 
        {
             <div>You must choose at least one item</div>
        }
```

I have the error message :

***The view 'Client' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Client.aspx
..
~/Views/Home/Client.cshtml
..***

but Home/Client.cshtml existe since it's the view

Thanks

Comment: you need to show the definition of your `form`. Also, `!Model.itemChoosed` is a server side code, it is static for client side

Comment: @ManishMishra I add the form definition

Comment: where are the three checkboxes?

Comment: You have a space in your `return View(" Client", ...)`

Comment: @ManishMishra three checkbox added

Comment: Do you have view with name Client.cshtml ?

Comment: @SpiderCode; yes actually the checkbox and the submit are in Client.cshtml, I want to user to stay at the same page if he didn't check at least one item, Client.cshtml is under Home

Comment: I resolve this by Adding a new AtionResult Client and renaming the existing Client to ChoiceValidation in the Controller that return View("Client", model)in the controller if the condition is not true